# Check whether class constructor defines method

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is a simple question: I want to check whether a class constructor has a method defined. For example:

```js
class MyClass {
  myMethod() { }
}

hasMethodDefined(MyClass, 'myMethod'); // true
hasMethodDefined(MyClass, 'whatever'); // false
```

I want that to be possible without having to create an instance of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 3):

Those methods are defined on the prototype:

```
MyClass.prototype.hasOwnProperty('myMethod')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think just simply check this:

```js
const hasMethod = !!MyClass.prototype.myMethod
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure it both exists **and** is a function, you look for it on the object that the constructor will assign as the prototype of instances, which is on the `prototype` property of the constructor function, and check that they're type `"function"`.

As a function:

```
const hasMethodDefined = (obj, methodName) => typeof obj[methodName] === "function";
```

Or with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to allow for passing in `null` or `undefined` as `obj` and getting `false` rather than an error (I'd prefer the error, but there are use cases for doing this as well):

```
const hasMethodDefined = (obj, methodName) => typeof obj?.[methodName] === "function";
```

Usage if you want to check the class:

```
if (hasMethodDefined(MyClass.prototype, "myMethod") {
    // ...
}
```

Or if you have an instance and want to check it:

```
if (hasMethodDefined(theInstance, "myMethod") {
    // ...
}
```

---

In the really unusual case where you only have access to an instance (you don't know the constructor, or don't directly have access to it) and want to know whether the prototype the constructor that created it gives to objects has the method, you can do this:

```
if (typeof theInstance.constructor?.prototype?.myMethod === "function") {
    // The instance has a `constructor` property, which refers to
    // something with a `prototype` property, which has a property
    // called "myMethod" that refers to a function
}
```

Or with the optional-chaining version of `hasMethodDefined` from earlier:

```
if (hasMethodDefined(theInstance.constructor?.prototype)) {
    // The instance has a `constructor` property, which refers to
    // something with a `prototype` property, which has a property
    // called "myMethod" that refers to a function
}
```