# check if class has method in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

How to check the existence of move() and run() methods shortly and safely?
hasOwnProperty returns false of course for both move and run.
dog.prototype is undefined so this isn't a way to start.

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} makes a noise.`);
  }
  move() // this method may exist or not
  {
      console.log(`${this.name} moves over.`);
  }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name); 
  }
  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} barks.`);
  }
  run() // this method may exist or not
  {
      console.log(`${this.name} runs fast.`);
  }
}
var dog = new Dog('Caesar');
// in the real-world situation we don't know the type of "dog" here.
```

How to check if dog.run() exists and invokable?
How to check if dog.move() exists and invokable?

**Edit:**
The marked-for-duplicate Q/A ([Check whether class constructor defines method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447621/check-whether-class-constructor-defines-method)) does not answer my question.

The final comment-note in my original post is important:
**in the real-world situation we don't know the type of "dog"**
So, I cannot write `Animal.prototype` or `Dog.prototype` because I don't know Animal and/or Dog. All I have is

- a reference to an object (dog),
- knowing that dog is created with a `new ClassName` statement where ClassName is a class defined by the class-syntax.

Comment: Re your edit: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70558021/157247) to that question does address the case of just having `dog`. (And I just thought of another wrinkle I'll edit into it.)

Comment: Thanks, `const hasMethodDefined = (obj, methodName) => typeof obj[methodName] === "function";` really works.